# introdution to Graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

I recently had my midterm and this was one of the questions I could not tackle upon I'm just curious to know how would the problem be solved

Comment: Did you understand the concepts involved by the question? Can you visualise the graph?

Comment: This is not a "know a procedure for this kind of problems" type of problem. It is a "understand the definitions" problem. If you know and understand the definitions, listing the subgraphs is a just-do-it task. If you don't ... well that is the kind of thing the exam is designed to discover. Success!

Answer (score 1):

An subgraph of a graph $G$ is any graph whose vertices and edges are a subset of those in $G$. In your example, $H=V_h,E_h$ where $V_h={x,y}$ and $E_H={{xy}}$ is one example.

An induced subgraph of $G$ is the same as a subgraph but must contain *all* of the edges in $G$ between vertices in the subset. The $H$ above is also an example of an induced subgraph.

A labelled subgraph means that even if two subgraphs of $G$ *look* the same (for example, if they both contain only two adjacent vertices), if they contain any different vertices or different edges from each other, then they are considered different. In other words, if two subgraphs are non-isomorphic, then we count them as two labelled subgraphs (the labels of the vertices do not matter). Thus the subgraph of $G$ containing $x$ and $y$ and the edge $xy$ and the subgraph containing $y$ and $z$ and the edge $yz$ are counted as two different labelled subgraphs.